# How do I find a pattern on the screen?

Tags: c++, click, bots, screen-capture

I thought I would try out making a bot to play a game on a website for me. How can I read the pixels of the screen? My best idea so far is basically:

1. Take screenshot
2. Scan screenshot for other images (bit comparison of one row in image?)
3. Click somewhere on the screen depending on what image was found.
4. Loop a few times per second

If this is the best/easiest way to do this: How do I do these things? I know some c++ but I've only worked with CLI programs and text/file IO so far. If you can think of a better way please tell me.

Comment: I just hope it's more of Tetris than of a first person shooter.

Comment: depends on the kind of game. An image text parser worked wonders for a diablo bot back in the day.

Comment: We're talking about 2D games only.    
    
What do you mean by image text parser?

Answer (score 0):

Using something like C# you can take screenshots of the screen and convert the resulting image to a Bitmap to do this, but it seems to me that you'd be better off looking at the HTML page on the wire (lookup a tutorial on how HTTP works or run wireshark to see how the page is transmitted on the wire). This will almost certainly be easier for you.

Comment: I know C# better than c++. I would like to learn how to do this without reverse engineering the data sent to/from the server. Do you have any tutorial on the subject?